# Flutter - WebView not working for Android

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutterwebviewplugin

Been seeing an issue using `flutter_webview_plugin: ^0.3.10+1` when launching from an android device. Everything works as expected when launching from iOS, both actual device and emulator.

When launching from Android, it looks like it tries to launch the webview and the spinner just keeps spinning and the below is what appears in the debug console. If anyone has any ideas what could be happening, if maybe a flutter upgrade broke this for android, please offer any idea!

Thanks for looking.

`I/WebViewFactory( 7409): Loading com.google.android.webview version 74.0.3729.185 (code 373018518)
I/neinsurance.pr( 7409): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/neinsurance.pr( 7409): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/cr_LibraryLoader( 7409): Time to load native libraries: 12 ms (timestamps 8589-8601)
I/chromium( 7409): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(50)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
I/cr_LibraryLoader( 7409): Expected native library version number "74.0.3729.185", actual native library version number "74.0.3729.185"
W/cr_ChildProcLH( 7409): Create a new ChildConnectionAllocator with package name = com.google.android.webview, sandboxed = true
W/neinsurance.pr( 7409): Accessing hidden method Landroid/content/Context;->bindServiceAsUser(Landroid/content/Intent;Landroid/content/ServiceConnection;ILandroid/os/Handler;Landroid/os/UserHandle;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
I/cr_BrowserStartup( 7409): Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=false
W/neinsurance.pr( 7409): Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker;-><init>(Landroid/content/Context;I)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/neinsurance.pr( 7409): Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker;->logEvent(Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/neinsurance.pr( 7409): Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionStarted(I)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/neinsurance.pr( 7409): Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionModified(II)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/neinsurance.pr( 7409): Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionModified(IILandroid/view/textclassifier/TextClassification;)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/neinsurance.pr( 7409): Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionModified(IILandroid/view/textclassifier/TextSelection;)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/neinsurance.pr( 7409): Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionAction(III)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/neinsurance.pr( 7409): Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionAction(IIILandroid/view/textclassifier/TextClassification;)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/cr_media( 7409): Requires BLUETOOTH permission
D/HostConnection( 7409): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb4551950, tid 8414
D/HostConnection( 7409): HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7409): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/EGL_emulation( 7409): eglCreateContext: 0xbe5097c0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/EGL_emulation( 7409): eglMakeCurrent: 0xbe5097c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xb45830d0)
E/eglCodecCommon( 7409): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
E/eglCodecCommon( 7409): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
D/eglCodecCommon( 7409): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 1 0
I/VideoCapabilities( 7409): Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
W/cr_MediaCodecUtil( 7409): HW encoder for video/avc is not available on this device.
D/eglCodecCommon( 7409): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 2
D/eglCodecCommon( 7409): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 2
D/NetworkSecurityConfig( 7409): No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/eglCodecCommon( 7409): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/EGL_emulation( 7409): eglCreateContext: 0xb45d4d20: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/EGL_emulation( 7409): eglMakeCurrent: 0xb45d4d20: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xb45830d0)
E/eglCodecCommon( 7409): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
E/eglCodecCommon( 7409): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
D/eglCodecCommon( 7409): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 0 0
E/eglCodecCommon( 7409): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
E/eglCodecCommon( 7409): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
D/eglCodecCommon( 7409): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 2 (2) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7409): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 2
I/chatty  ( 7409): uid=10139(com.frontlineinsurance.pro) RenderThread identical 14 lines
D/eglCodecCommon( 7409): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 2
D/eglCodecCommon( 7409): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7409): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 2 (2) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7409): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 1 8
D/eglCodecCommon( 7409): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 2`

Comment: Did you got any solution?

Comment: @AdarshGJ unfortunately not, ended up switching over to flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer as all I was doing was viewing pdfs in the webview. worked for me.